# Store users' activity in Sagitta component

Tags: fiware, fiware-sagitta

If I use Sagitta in order to install and uninstall any product from its catalogue, 
does the Sagitta store all the users’ activity related to installation and uninstallation of products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. Saggita handles and stores the activity of the users regarding installation/uninstallation products per virtual machine in a database.